# Unable to change "Paragraph Settings" to adjust table location (greyed out)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lyx

I'm new to Lyx. I just complete the install. I am trying to set a table to be centered in the page, which I am trying to do by right clicking within the table and selecting "Paragraph Settings". However, the "Paragraph Settings" option is greyed out (i.e. I cannot click on it).

I set up the table using the "Insert Table" icon within the banner.

Any advice?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to right click *outside* (beside, not above/below) the table, then you can adjust the setting for the paragraph in which the table is placed. Right clicking in the table is for changing things in the table itself, but that is separate to how the table is placed on the page.